# Home "server" interafearing with IPTV

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, interference, iptv

On my home network, I have connected a computer("server") running a bunch of services and containers (such as Plex, Home Assistant, Ajenti, Transmission...) which, seems to, making trouble with IPTV service on the same network. 
The network looks something like this:

ISP (optic fiber) router -> Gigabit switch -> 2 Asus routers as Wifi APs

The set-top box is connected directly to the ISP router. The "server" was connected either to the switch or to the ISP router - the result was the same.

The issue is that in the evening some TV channels (both SD or HD) freeze or scheduled recording doesn't work.

Thought it was an ISP issue, however if the "server" was turned off for a week TV worked fine.

Then I thought it might be that ISP router is insufficient for DHCP server - however, so far I did not manage to transfer DHCP server to the "server" from ISP router.

Before I had one of Asus the routers configurated as DHCP and it was on separate network segment and as far as I remember TV worked fine then.

Also, I tried to move IPTV to a separate segment but didn't help.

So, please, could you give me advice on what could cause this issue or where should I start with debugging? I probably missed some important info so please let me know what I missed. Thanks

Comment: Please speak to your ISP.

Comment: Thank you, tried that, didn't help.

Comment: You have a couple PC's to test with?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution was to move the whole network to another subnet and set one of the APs routers as DHCP server for the network.
Apparently, ISP router was not enough for serving IPTV and DHCP servers for the whole network.

Thank you guys anyway :)